Flutter HomeScreen Widget background update
Anyone who has used this https://pub.dev/packages/home_widget library?
I need to update the data in the HomeScreen Widget every day. I use this library https://pub.dev/packages/background_fetch to run the background process even though the app is terminated but it seems it doesn't work.
Is there any reference or sample that is the same approach as my case for Android and iOS?
I've tried to implement and follow the instructions about the implementation background_fetch but it doesn't work. I checked the widget the next day but the widget still shows the old data.

Code to run the task in the background
main.dart
runApp(MyApp());

 // Register to receive BackgroundFetch events after app is terminated.
 // Requires {stopOnTerminate: false, enableHeadless: true}

BackgroundFetch.registerHeadlessTask(backgroundFetchHeadlessTask);


home_widget.dart
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
Future<void> backgroundFetchHeadlessTask(HeadlessTask task) async {
  final taskId = task.taskId;
  final timeout = task.timeout;
  if (timeout) {
    logger.d("[BackgroundFetch] Headless task timed-out: $taskId");
    BackgroundFetch.finish(taskId);
    return;
  }

   /// fetch data from API
   final result = fetchDataFromAPI();

   await HomeWidget.saveWidgetData(
        homeWidgetData[x]["id"],
        homeWidgetData[x]["value"],
      );

   /// update home widget data
    HomeWidget.updateWidget(
      name: 'PrayerTimeWidgetProvider',
      androidName: 'PrayerTimeWidgetProvider',
      iOSName: 'PrayerTimeWidget',
      qualifiedAndroidName:
          'com.xxx.xxx.xx.xxx.xx',
    );

 BackgroundFetch.scheduleTask(
      TaskConfig(
        taskId: "com.transistorsoft.fetch",
        delay: 60 * 60 * 1000,

        /// will fetch every 1 hour
        periodic: true,
        startOnBoot: true,
        forceAlarmManager: true,
        stopOnTerminate: false,
        enableHeadless: true,
      ),
    );

}



Can you share the snippets of the code that you have written to acheive this?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Not much of the app is initialized in the callback function (the one under @pragma('vm:entry-point')) and lots of things could be failing there silently (it won't crash or anything, won't even see it in the debugger). So I would suggest putting everything in your callback in a try / catch and printing the errors explicitly in debug to see if something's failing there.
